# remove news item from the joomla newsflash

Tags: joomla

I am using the joomla newsflash in order to display the 5 most recent items in my home page. the newsflash is attached to my news & events category. now I need that one of the news & events items will not be displayed in my home newsFlash. is it possible?, thanks

Comment: What's the criterion that you want remove for? The most recent? A specific article?

Comment: I need to remove a specific article that one of the site users entered to the news & events section. its ok in the news& events section but I don't want that it will be shown in the home page

Comment: What version of Joomla? I'm guessing 1.5 since Newsflash isn't a core module in 2.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Joomla 1.5.26, a template override might be your best bet. See here for how that's done: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=145996

In your case, you'd create a new file at

```
/templates/your_template/html/mod_newsflash/_item.php
```

You'd put the following code in that file. Be sure to replace "99" with the id of your article. You can get that from the Article Manager table.

```
<?php // no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access'); ?>

<?php 
$my_article_id = $item->id;

if ($my_article_id !== '99') :

    if ($params->get('item_title')) : ?>
        <table class="contentpaneopen<?php echo $params->get( 'moduleclass_sfx' ); ?>">
        <tr>
            <td class="contentheading<?php echo $params->get( 'moduleclass_sfx' ); ?>" width="100%">
            <?php if ($params->get('link_titles') && $item->linkOn != '') : ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $item->linkOn;?>" class="contentpagetitle<?php echo $params->get( 'moduleclass_sfx' ); ?>">
                    <?php echo $item->title;?></a>
            <?php else : ?>
                <?php echo $item->title; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if (!$params->get('intro_only')) :
        echo $item->afterDisplayTitle;
    endif; ?>

    <?php echo $item->beforeDisplayContent; ?>

    <table class="contentpaneopen<?php echo $params->get( 'moduleclass_sfx' ); ?>">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" ><?php echo $item->text; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" >

           <?php if (isset($item->linkOn) && $item->readmore && $params->get('readmore')) :
              echo '<a class="readmore" href="'.$item->linkOn.'">'.$item->linkText.'</a>';
            endif; ?>
            </td>
         </tr>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The relevant code is in the second and final PHP tags, where I've inserted an IF check which looks for your article ID and skips it if it matches.